# How to only add to controller if commit is successful? Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

In the controller

```
this.get('store').createRecord(Emb.Painting, {name: n});
this.get('store').commit();
```

In the template

```
<ul>
{{#each controller}}
  <li>
    {{name}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can place a

```
didCreate: function() {
}
```

in your model. I could not find any direct callback.  I decided to add validation at my view layer.

Comment: Another option is to set up a computed property in your controller and use `.mapProperty('isNew', false)`